# awk - replace pattern

Tags: awk, gawk

how do I search the following pattern by awk in a file.

```
'\b'
```

The pattern is one of the lines in a file.
I have to add text next to the pattern. Like this:

```
'\b' TEXT
```

Any of these commands are not working
1.

```
 awk -e '/'\b'/ { sub($1,$1" TEXT")} 1' -i inplace file
```

2.

```
 awk -e '/\'\\b\'/ {sub($1,$1" TEXT")} 1' -i inplace file
```

Comment: Show an example of your input and your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is your incorrect use of `sub`:

```
awk '/\\b/ { $1 = $1" TEXT"} 1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `awk`, you could use `sed`:

```
sed -i "s/'\\\\b'/& TEXT/" file
```

The trick is the 4 `\` needed for both `bash` and `sed`.